# delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localdomain type=A: Host not found

Tags: email, postfix-mta

use email tool to send email to a test user i.e. isemailu5@slc00bly.us.oracle.com, email server is slc00bly.us.oracle.com.  and got the following issue, i think this should be some postfix configure issue, how should i to resolve it?:

```
ERROR:
Feb 25 22:27:25 slc00bly postfix/qmgr[8481]: E90041941394: to=<isemailu5@slc00bly.us.oracle.com>, relay=none, delay=0.04, delays=0.03/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localdomain type=A: Host not found)
Feb 25 22:27:25 slc00bly postfix/qmgr[8481]: EEE6B1941395: to=<isemailu5@slc00bly.us.oracle.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localdomain type=A: Host not found)

POSTFIX CONFIG:
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks_style = class
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost = $mydomain
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postfix
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem may be caused by your DNS server;

Edit "/etc/resolv.conf" and try:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.4
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

or your other DNS Server.

Answer (score 1):

I my case `status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com type=A: Host not found, try again)` error resolved after restarting NetworkManager

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me once, after /etc/resolv.conf change, that postfix somehow get stuck. A simple postfix reload fixed the problem.

Note: but before the reload, be sure your nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to DNS, I can confirm that since the same problem I faced and fixed by adding the correct DNS in `resolv.conf`